# How to get missing data from this result set?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

Based on two inputs - date (any date from calendar) and period of date (Year,month or week) result should aggregate data:

Please excuse me for the long text, but there is no way to explain too short,

for example; when @period is given as **YEAR** then it should aggregate results based on all months of that year, and for missing months it should be 0,

when @period is given as **MONTH** then it should aggregate results based on all dates of that specific month in that year, and for missing dates it should be 0,

when @period is given as **WEEK** then it should aggregate results based on the days (between first day and last day of the given week) in that specific week of that specific month and year, and for missing weekday it should be 0,

when @period is given as **DAY** then it should aggregate results based on the hours (0hrs to 23 hrs) in that given day, and for missing hour it should be 0.

1. Current code provides only the result for which the data is present in the table and I need the missing data as 0 for Month, Weekday & Hour

Here is the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[transferTable](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [transferDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [transferAmount] [money] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1000, CAST(0x0000AA2C0110897B AS DateTime), 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1001, CAST(0x0000AA2D00F0AA50 AS DateTime), 151.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1002, CAST(0x0000A8850110897B AS DateTime), 10.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1003, CAST(0x0000AA0E0121043B AS DateTime), 151.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1005, CAST(0x0000AA4B01220A00 AS DateTime), 70.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1006, CAST(0x0000AA4A013284C0 AS DateTime), 75.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1007, CAST(0x0000AA4401537A40 AS DateTime), 85.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1008, CAST(0x0000AA4F002AD8C0 AS DateTime), 20.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1009, CAST(0x0000AA4F003B5380 AS DateTime), 25.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1010, CAST(0x0000AA4F005C4900 AS DateTime), 45.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1011, CAST(0x0000AA4F005C4900 AS DateTime), 14.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1012, CAST(0x0000A8C4006CC3C0 AS DateTime), 66.0000)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[transferTable] OFF
GO
```

Actual Code:

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-04-16 05:00'
DECLARE @period varchar(10) = 'year'

DECLARE @year varchar(10) =  DATEPART(YEAR,@calenderDate) 
DECLARE @month varchar(10)=  DATEPART(MONTH,@calenderDate)
DECLARE @week varchar(10) =  DATEPART(WEEK,@calenderDate) 
DECLARE @hour varchar(10) =  DATEPART(HOUR,@calenderDate)

select  case when @period = 'YEAR' then DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime)
            when @period = 'MONTH' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
            when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime)
            when @period = 'DAY' then DATEPART(HOUR,transferDateTime)
        end as period, 
     COUNT (t.transferAmount) as volOfTxns,
     SUM (t.transferAmount) as ValueOfTxns
from transferTable t
where  
 (
        (@period = 'YEAR'   AND DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year)
    OR  (@period = 'MONTH'  AND ( DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month))
    OR  (@period = 'WEEK'   AND (DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month) AND DATEPART(WEEK,t.transferDateTime) = @week)
    OR  (@period = 'DAY'   AND (DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month) AND DATEPART(WEEK,t.transferDateTime) = @week AND DATEPART(HOUR,t.transferDateTime) = @hour)
    ) 


group by case when @period = 'YEAR' then DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'MONTH' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'DAY' then DATEPART(HOUR,transferDateTime)
          end
```

Problem 1 - I expect the missing data should show 0.

for example if the input is like below;

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-03-16 05:00'
DECLARE @period varchar(10) = 'year'
```

actual result is :

```
period  volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
3          1         151.00
4          2         161.00
5          7         334.00
```

expected result is : to show also the missing months in that year but with 0 values in period field (here the period field represents month).

```
period  volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
1         0                 0
2         0                 0
3         1                 151
4         2                 161
5         7                 334
6         0                 0
7         0                 0
8         0                 0
9         0                 0
10        0                 0
11        0                 0
12        0                 0
```

Likewise, if *@period = 'month'* it should show date 1 to 31 (or 1 to 30 based on that month)  (for missing days it should show 0) in  period field (here the period field represents date).

Likewise, if *@period = 'week'* it should show weekdays Sunday to Saturday (for missing weekday it should show 0)in  period field (here the period field represents weekday).

Likewise, if *@period = 'day'* it should show hours 00to 23 hrs (for missing hrs it should show 0) in  period field (here the period field represents hrs).

Comment: This query definitely suffers from being a [kitchen sink](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) but those arguments aren't SARGable either, making that query a nightmare for performance. Why do you need a one size fits all query here? Multiple queries would serve your far far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses recursive CTEs.  I've only prepared a script for Year and Month.  If this works for you, just add the additional conditions:

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-03-16 05:00'
Declare @day1Month Date = Cast(Year(@calenderDate) As Char(4)) + '-' + Cast(Month(@calenderDate) As Char(2)) + '-01'
Declare @Year Int = Year(@calenderDate)
Declare @Month Int = Month(@calenderDate)

DECLARE @period varchar(10) = 'Year' 

Declare @periodlst Table (period Int)
```

-------------------------------------------> Get Periods listing

```
If @period = 'Year'  --List numbers 1 to 12
          Insert @periodlst Select * From ( Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12) ) p(period);
Else If @period = 'Month'  --List numbers 1 to end of month
       with numcte AS  
       (  
         SELECT 1 [num]  
         UNION all  
         SELECT [num] + 1 FROM numcte WHERE [num] < (Select  datediff(day, @day1Month, dateadd(month, 1, @day1Month)))
       )        
       Insert @periodlst Select * FROM numcte
```

--------------------------------------------------> Recursive CTE

```
;With cte As
(
Select 
       Case When @period = 'Year' Then Month(transferDateTime) 
            When @period = 'Month' Then Day(transferDateTime)
        End As period    
       ,* 
From transferTable Where 
       (@period = 'Year' And Year(transferDateTime) = @Year) Or
       (@period = 'Month' And Year(transferDateTime) = @Year And Month(transferDateTime) = @Month) 
)
, cte1 As
(
         Select * From @periodlst
)
Select 
     cte1.period As periods, 
     Count(TransferAmount) As volOfTxns,
     IsNull(Sum(TransferAmount),0) As valueOfTxns
From cte1 Left Join cte On
     cte.period = cte1.period
     Group By cte1.period
```

Answer (score 2):

Using rangeAB (T-SQL code below) it's easy.

Turn your query into subquery. Use rangeAB to generate the numbers you need, (e.g. 1-12 for when YEAR is selected). Then LEFT JOIN your subquery to the rangeAB query.

```
SELECT 
  [period]    = r.RN,
  volOfTxns   = ISNULL(t.volOfTxns,0),
  ValueOfTxns = ISNULL(t.ValueOfTxns,0)
FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,12,1,1) AS r
LEFT JOIN
(
  select  case when @period = 'YEAR' then DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'MONTH' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime)
              when @period = 'DAY' then DATEPART(HOUR,transferDateTime)
          end as period, 
       COUNT (t.transferAmount) as volOfTxns,
       SUM (t.transferAmount) as ValueOfTxns
  from      transferTable AS t
  where  
   (
          (@period = 'YEAR'   AND DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year)
      OR  (@period = 'MONTH'  AND ( DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month))
      OR  (@period = 'WEEK'   AND (DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month) AND DATEPART(WEEK,t.transferDateTime) = @week)
      OR  (@period = 'DAY'   AND (DATEPART(YEAR,t.transferDateTime) = @year AND DATEPART(MONTH,t.transferDateTime) = @month) AND DATEPART(WEEK,t.transferDateTime) = @week AND DATEPART(HOUR,t.transferDateTime) = @hour)
      ) 


  group by case when @period = 'YEAR' then DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime)
                when @period = 'MONTH' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
                when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime)
                when @period = 'DAY' then DATEPART(HOUR,transferDateTime)
            END
) AS t ON r.RN = t.[period];
```

**Returns:**

```
period               volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
-------------------- ----------- ---------------------
1                    0           0.00
2                    0           0.00
3                    1           151.00
4                    2           161.00
5                    7           334.00
6                    0           0.00
7                    0           0.00
8                    0           0.00
9                    0           0.00
10                   0           0.00
11                   0           0.00
12                   0           0.00
```

To handle multiple periods you would change the number 12 in rangeAB(1,12,1,1) to an expression/Case statement where the upper number is based on whatever logic you are using for other types of periods.

**RangeAB code:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.rangeAB
(
  @low  BIGINT, 
  @high BIGINT, 
  @gap  BIGINT,
  @row1 BIT
)
/****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]:
 Creates up to 531,441,000,000 sequentia1 integers numbers beginning with @low and ending 
 with @high. Used to replace iterative methods such as loops, cursors and recursive CTEs 
 to solve SQL problems. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's getnums function with some tweeks and 
 enhancements and added functionality. The logic for getting rn to begin at 0 or 1 is 
 based comes from Jeff Moden's fnTally function. 

 The name range because it's similar to clojure's range function. The name "rangeAB" as 
 used because "range" is a reserved SQL keyword.

[Author]: Alan Burstein

[Compatibility]: 
 SQL Server 2008+ and Azure SQL Database

[Syntax]:
 SELECT r.RN, r.OP, r.N1, r.N2
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(@low,@high,@gap,@row1) AS r;

[Parameters]:
 @low  = a bigint that represents the lowest value for n1.
 @high = a bigint that represents the highest value for n1.
 @gap  = a bigint that represents how much n1 and n2 will increase each row; @gap also
         represents the difference between n1 and n2.
 @row1 = a bit that represents the first value of rn. When @row = 0 then rn begins
         at 0, when @row = 1 then rn will begin at 1.

[Returns]:
 Inline Table Valued Function returns:
 rn = bigint; a row number that works just like T-SQL ROW_NUMBER() except that it can 
      start at 0 or 1 which is dictated by @row1.
 op = bigint; returns the "opposite number that relates to rn. When rn begins with 0 and
      ends with 10 then 10 is the opposite of 0, 9 the opposite of 1, etc. When rn begins
      with 1 and ends with 5 then 1 is the opposite of 5, 2 the opposite of 4, etc...
 n1 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low and incrimentingby the
      value of @gap until it is less than or equal to the value of @high.
 n2 = bigint; a sequential number starting at the value of @low+@gap and  incrimenting 
      by the value of @gap.

[Dependencies]:
N/A

[Developer Notes]:

 1. The lowest and highest possible numbers returned are whatever is allowable by a 
    bigint. The function, however, returns no more than 531,441,000,000 rows (8100^3). 
 2. @gap does not affect rn, rn will begin at @row1 and increase by 1 until the last row
    unless its used in a query where a filter is applied to rn.
 3. @gap must be greater than 0 or the function will not return any rows.
 4. Keep in mind that when @row1 is 0 then the highest row-number will be the number of
    rows returned minus 1
 5. If you only need is a sequential set beginning at 0 or 1 then, for best performance
    use the RN column. Use N1 and/or N2 when you need to begin your sequence at any 
    number other than 0 or 1 or if you need a gap between your sequence of numbers. 
 6. Although @gap is a bigint it must be a positive integer or the function will
    not return any rows.
 7. The function will not return any rows when one of the following conditions are true:
      * any of the input parameters are NULL
      * @high is less than @low 
      * @gap is not greater than 0
    To force the function to return all NULLs instead of not returning anything you can
    add the following code to the end of the query:

      UNION ALL 
      SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
      WHERE NOT (@high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0)

    This code was excluded as it adds a ~5% performance penalty.
 8. There is no performance penalty for sorting by rn ASC; there is a large performance 
    penalty for sorting in descending order WHEN @row1 = 1; WHEN @row1 = 0
    If you need a descending sort the use op in place of rn then sort by rn ASC. 

Best Practices:
--===== 1. Using RN (rownumber)
 -- (1.1) The best way to get the numbers 1,2,3...@high (e.g. 1 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1);
 -- (1.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 0 to 5):
 SELECT RN FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,5,1,0);

--===== 2. Using OP for descending sorts without a performance penalty
 -- (2.1) The best way to get the numbers 5,4,3...@high (e.g. 5 to 1):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,5,1,1) ORDER BY rn ASC;
 -- (2.2) The best way to get the numbers 0,1,2...@high-1 (e.g. 5 to 0):
 SELECT op FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,6,1,0) ORDER BY rn ASC;

--===== 3. Using N1
 -- (3.1) To begin with numbers other than 0 or 1 use N1 (e.g. -3 to 3):
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.2) ROW_NUMBER() is built in. If you want a ROW_NUMBER() include RN:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,1);
 -- (3.3) If you wanted a ROW_NUMBER() that started at 0 you would do this:
 SELECT RN, N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(-3,3,1,0);

--===== 4. Using N2 and @gap
 -- (4.1) To get 0,10,20,30...100, set @low to 0, @high to 100 and @gap to 10:
 SELECT N1 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,100,10,1);
 -- (4.2) Note that N2=N1+@gap; this allows you to create a sequence of ranges.
 --       For example, to get (0,10),(10,20),(20,30).... (90,100):
 SELECT N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);
 -- (4.3) Remember that a rownumber is included and it can begin at 0 or 1:
 SELECT RN, N1, N2 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,90,10,1);

[Examples]:
--===== 1. Generating Sample data (using rangeAB to create "dummy rows")
 -- The query below will generate 10,000 ids and random numbers between 50,000 and 500,000
 SELECT
   someId    = r.rn,
   someNumer = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%450000)+50001 
 FROM rangeAB(1,10000,1,1) r;

--===== 2. Create a series of dates; rn is 0 to include the first date in the series
 DECLARE @startdate DATE = '20180101', @enddate DATE = '20180131';

 SELECT r.rn, calDate = DATEADD(dd, r.rn, @startdate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, DATEDIFF(dd,@startdate,@enddate),1,0) r;
 GO

--===== 3. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with fixed sized items
 -- given a delimited string of identifiers that are always 7 characters long
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'A601225,B435223,G008081,R678567';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = r.rn, -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING(@string, r.n1, 7) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1, LEN(@string), 8,1)  r;
 GO

--===== 4. Splitting (tokenizing) a string with random delimiters
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABC123,999F,XX,9994443335';

 SELECT
   itemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY r.rn), -- item's ordinal position 
   itemIndex  = r.n1+1, -- item's position in the string (it's CHARINDEX value)
   item       = SUBSTRING
               (
                 @string,
                 r.n1+1,
                 ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',',@string,r.n1+1),0)-r.n1-1, 8000)
               ) -- item (token)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,DATALENGTH(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.n1,1) = ',' OR r.n1 = 0;
 -- logic borrowed from: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

--===== 5. Grouping by a weekly intervals
 -- 5.1. how to create a series of start/end dates between @startDate & @endDate
 DECLARE @startDate DATE = '1/1/2015', @endDate DATE = '2/1/2015';
 SELECT 
   WeekNbr   = r.RN,
   WeekStart = DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate), 
   WeekEnd   = DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r;
 GO

 -- 5.2. LEFT JOIN to the weekly interval table
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @startDate datetime = '1/1/2015', @endDate datetime = '2/1/2015';
  -- sample data 
  DECLARE @loans TABLE (loID INT, lockDate DATE);
  INSERT @loans SELECT r.rn, DATEADD(dd, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%32), @startDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,50,1,1) r;

  -- solution 
  SELECT 
    WeekNbr   = r.RN,
    WeekStart = dt.WeekStart, 
    WeekEnd   = dt.WeekEnd,
    total     = COUNT(l.lockDate)
  FROM dbo.rangeAB(0,datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate),7,1) r
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N1,@StartDate) AS DATE), 
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,r.N2-1,@StartDate) AS DATE))) dt(WeekStart,WeekEnd)
  LEFT JOIN @loans l ON l.lockDate BETWEEN  dt.WeekStart AND dt.WeekEnd
  GROUP BY r.RN, dt.WeekStart, dt.WeekEnd ;
 END;

--===== 6. Identify the first vowel and last vowel in a along with their positions
 DECLARE @string VARCHAR(200) = 'This string has vowels';

 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.rn, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

 -- To avoid a sort in the execution plan we'll use op instead of rn
 SELECT TOP(1) position = r.op, letter = SUBSTRING(@string,r.op,1)
 FROM dbo.rangeAB(1,LEN(@string),1,1) r
 WHERE SUBSTRING(@string,r.rn,1) LIKE '%[aeiou]%'
 ORDER BY r.rn;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Revision History]:
 Rev 00 - 20140518 - Initial Development - Alan Burstein
 Rev 01 - 20151029 - Added 65 rows to make L1=465; 465^3=100.5M. Updated comment section
                   - Alan Burstein
 Rev 02 - 20180613 - Complete re-design including opposite number column (op)
 Rev 03 - 20180920 - Added additional CROSS JOIN to L2 for 530B rows max - Alan Burstein
****************************************************************************************/
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
WITH L1(N) AS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM (VALUES
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),
   (0),(0)) T(N) -- 90 values 
),
L2(N)  AS (SELECT 1 FROM L1 a CROSS JOIN L1 b CROSS JOIN L1 c),
iTally AS (SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM L2 a CROSS JOIN L2 b)
SELECT
  r.RN,
  r.OP,
  r.N1,
  r.N2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    RN = 0,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap,
    N1 = @low,
    N2 = @gap+@low
  WHERE @row1 = 0
  UNION ALL -- COALESCE required in the TOP statement below for error handling purposes
  SELECT TOP (ABS((COALESCE(@high,0)-COALESCE(@low,0))/COALESCE(@gap,0)+COALESCE(@row1,1)))
    RN = i.rn,
    OP = (@high-@low)/@gap+(2*@row1)-i.rn,
    N1 = (i.rn-@row1)*@gap+@low,
    N2 = (i.rn-(@row1-1))*@gap+@low
  FROM iTally AS i
  ORDER BY i.rn
) AS r
WHERE @high&@low&@gap&@row1 IS NOT NULL AND @high >= @low AND @gap > 0;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the Week is treated incorrectly and will give different result than the one expected by your query, so I will build the periods by CTE ,join it with your data and do some modifications too.

I tested all periods 'YEAR','MONTH','WEEK','DAY' and showing the results too.

my long query (based on yours) is as follow:-

```
DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-05-16 05:00'
DECLARE @period varchar(10) = 'YEAR' -- 'MONTH' or 'WEEK''DAY'

--find the start and end for each period
Declare @PeriodStart datetime,@PeriodEnd datetime
select @PeriodStart=case    when @period = 'YEAR' then cast(cast(year(@calenderDate) as varchar(4))+'-01-01' as datetime)
                            when @period = 'MONTH' then cast(cast(year(@calenderDate) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(Month(@calenderDate) as varchar(2))+'-01' as datetime)
                            when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, cast(@calenderDate as date))-1), cast(@calenderDate as date))
                            when @period = 'DAY' then cast(cast(year(@calenderDate) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(month(@calenderDate) as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(day(@calenderDate)as varchar(2)) as datetime) end

select @PeriodEnd=case      when @period = 'YEAR' then dateadd(MILLISECOND,-3,dateadd(month,12,@PeriodStart))
                            when @period = 'MONTH' then dateadd(MILLISECOND,-3,dateadd(month,1,@PeriodStart))
                            when @period = 'WEEK' then dateadd(MILLISECOND,-3,dateadd(day,7,@PeriodStart))
                            when @period = 'DAY' then dateadd(MILLISECOND,-3,dateadd(hour,24,@PeriodStart)) end

;with PeriodYear as (
    select @PeriodStart [Period]
    union all
    select dateadd(month,1,PeriodYear.[Period]) from PeriodYear where dateadd(month,1,PeriodYear.[Period])<=@PeriodEnd
),PeriodMonth as (
    select @PeriodStart [Period]
    union all
    select dateadd(DAY,1,PeriodMonth.[Period]) from PeriodMonth where dateadd(DAY,1,PeriodMonth.[Period])<=@PeriodEnd
),PeriodWeek as (
    select @PeriodStart [Period]
    union all
    select dateadd(DAY,1,PeriodWeek.[Period]) from PeriodWeek where dateadd(DAY,1,PeriodWeek.[Period])<=@PeriodEnd
),PeriodDay as (
    select @PeriodStart [Period]
    union all
    select dateadd(hour,1,PeriodDay.[Period]) from PeriodDay where dateadd(hour,1,PeriodDay.[Period])<=@PeriodEnd
),GroupData as (
    select case 
            when @period = 'YEAR'       then cast(cast(DATEPART(year,min(transferDateTime)) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(DATEPART(MONTH,min(transferDateTime)) as varchar(2))+'-01' as datetime)
            when @period = 'MONTH'      then cast(cast(min(transferDateTime) as date) as datetime)
            when @period = 'WEEK'       then cast(cast(min(transferDateTime) as date) as datetime)
            when @period = 'DAY'        then dateadd(hour,DATEPART(HOUR,min(transferDateTime)),cast(cast(min(transferDateTime) as date) as datetime))
        end as [period], 
         COUNT (t.transferAmount) as volOfTxns,
         SUM (t.transferAmount) as ValueOfTxns
    from transferTable t
    where  
        t.transferDateTime between @PeriodStart and @PeriodEnd 
    group by case when @period = 'YEAR' then DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime)
                  when @period = 'MONTH' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
                  when @period = 'WEEK' then DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime)
                  when @period = 'DAY' then DATEPART(HOUR,transferDateTime)
              end
),RangeDataSet as (
    select * from PeriodYear where @period = 'YEAR' union all 
    select * from PeriodMonth where @period = 'MONTH' union all 
    select * from PeriodWeek where @period = 'WEEK' union all 
    select * from PeriodDay where @period = 'DAY'
)
select RangeDataSet.[Period] [PeriodDate]
,case             when @period = 'YEAR'     then cast(DATEPART(MONTH,RangeDataSet.[Period])   as varchar(50))
                  when @period = 'MONTH'    then cast(DATEPART(DAY,RangeDataSet.[Period])     as varchar(50))
                  when @period = 'WEEK'     then cast(datename(WEEKDAY,RangeDataSet.[Period]) as varchar(50))
                  when @period = 'DAY'      then cast(Right('00' + cast(DATEPART(HOUR,RangeDataSet.[Period]) as varchar(2)),2) as varchar(50))+' hrs'
              end [Period]
,isnull(volOfTxns,0) volOfTxns,isnull(ValueOfTxns,0) ValueOfTxns from RangeDataSet
left outer join GroupData on GroupData.[Period]=RangeDataSet.[Period]
```

result for each period type

For Year

```
PeriodDate  Period  volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 1   0   0.00
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000 2   0   0.00
2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 3   1   151.00
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000 4   2   161.00
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 5   7   334.00
2019-06-01 00:00:00.000 6   0   0.00
2019-07-01 00:00:00.000 7   0   0.00
2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 8   0   0.00
2019-09-01 00:00:00.000 9   0   0.00
2019-10-01 00:00:00.000 10  0   0.00
2019-11-01 00:00:00.000 11  0   0.00
2019-12-01 00:00:00.000 12  0   0.00
```

For Month

```
PeriodDate  Period  volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000 1   0   0.00
2019-05-02 00:00:00.000 2   0   0.00
2019-05-03 00:00:00.000 3   0   0.00
2019-05-04 00:00:00.000 4   0   0.00
2019-05-05 00:00:00.000 5   1   85.00
2019-05-06 00:00:00.000 6   0   0.00
2019-05-07 00:00:00.000 7   0   0.00
2019-05-08 00:00:00.000 8   0   0.00
2019-05-09 00:00:00.000 9   0   0.00
2019-05-10 00:00:00.000 10  0   0.00
2019-05-11 00:00:00.000 11  1   75.00
2019-05-12 00:00:00.000 12  1   70.00
2019-05-13 00:00:00.000 13  0   0.00
2019-05-14 00:00:00.000 14  0   0.00
2019-05-15 00:00:00.000 15  0   0.00
2019-05-16 00:00:00.000 16  4   104.00
2019-05-17 00:00:00.000 17  0   0.00
2019-05-18 00:00:00.000 18  0   0.00
2019-05-19 00:00:00.000 19  0   0.00
2019-05-20 00:00:00.000 20  0   0.00
2019-05-21 00:00:00.000 21  0   0.00
2019-05-22 00:00:00.000 22  0   0.00
2019-05-23 00:00:00.000 23  0   0.00
2019-05-24 00:00:00.000 24  0   0.00
2019-05-25 00:00:00.000 25  0   0.00
2019-05-26 00:00:00.000 26  0   0.00
2019-05-27 00:00:00.000 27  0   0.00
2019-05-28 00:00:00.000 28  0   0.00
2019-05-29 00:00:00.000 29  0   0.00
2019-05-30 00:00:00.000 30  0   0.00
2019-05-31 00:00:00.000 31  0   0.00
```

For Week showing 7 days

```
PeriodDate  Period                 volOfTxns    ValueOfTxns
2019-05-12 00:00:00.000 Sunday     1             70.00
2019-05-13 00:00:00.000 Monday     0             0.00
2019-05-14 00:00:00.000 Tuesday    0             0.00
2019-05-15 00:00:00.000 Wednesday   0            0.00
2019-05-16 00:00:00.000 Thursday    4            104.00
2019-05-17 00:00:00.000 Friday     0             0.00
2019-05-18 00:00:00.000 Saturday    0            0.00
```

For Day

```
 PeriodDate Period  volOfTxns   ValueOfTxns
2019-05-16 00:00:00.000 00 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 01:00:00.000 01 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 02:00:00.000 02 hrs  1   20.00
2019-05-16 03:00:00.000 03 hrs  1   25.00
2019-05-16 04:00:00.000 04 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 05:00:00.000 05 hrs  2   59.00
2019-05-16 06:00:00.000 06 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 07:00:00.000 07 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 08:00:00.000 08 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 09:00:00.000 09 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 10:00:00.000 10 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 11:00:00.000 11 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 12:00:00.000 12 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 13:00:00.000 13 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 14:00:00.000 14 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 15:00:00.000 15 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 16:00:00.000 16 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 17:00:00.000 17 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 18:00:00.000 18 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 19:00:00.000 19 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 20:00:00.000 20 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 21:00:00.000 21 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 22:00:00.000 22 hrs  0   0.00
2019-05-16 23:00:00.000 23 hrs  0   0.00
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of approaching the same problem. Rather than submitting the date mode as a parameter and then conditionally summing based on the parameter passed in, a rollup grouping will allow you to display all of the date permutations hierarchically. Meaning the year takes precedence over the month, the month over the day and so on.

To prevent null values I have coalesced the dateparts which has also forced me to add some jigging in to the order by clause so that the day numbers come out the right way around.

Final note,  the @calendarday parameter is used to give a >= where clause, meaning this result set will show transactions for May, but you could switch this around if you want to, meaning you get an overall sense of the data before this point.

```
CREATE TABLE #transferTable(
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1000,1) NOT NULL,
    [transferDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [transferAmount] [money] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #transfertable ON 

GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1000, CAST(0x0000AA2C0110897B AS DateTime), 10.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1001, CAST(0x0000AA2D00F0AA50 AS DateTime), 151.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1002, CAST(0x0000A8850110897B AS DateTime), 10.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1003, CAST(0x0000AA0E0121043B AS DateTime), 151.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1005, CAST(0x0000AA4B01220A00 AS DateTime), 70.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1006, CAST(0x0000AA4A013284C0 AS DateTime), 75.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1007, CAST(0x0000AA4401537A40 AS DateTime), 85.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1008, CAST(0x0000AA4F002AD8C0 AS DateTime), 20.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1009, CAST(0x0000AA4F003B5380 AS DateTime), 25.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1010, CAST(0x0000AA4F005C4900 AS DateTime), 45.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1011, CAST(0x0000AA4F005C4900 AS DateTime), 14.0000)
GO
INSERT #transfertable ([ID], [transferDateTime], [transferAmount]) VALUES (1012, CAST(0x0000A8C4006CC3C0 AS DateTime), 66.0000)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #transfertable OFF
GO

DECLARE @calenderDate DATETIME2(0) = '2019-04-16 05:00'

DECLARE @year varchar(10) =  DATEPART(YEAR,@calenderDate) 
DECLARE @month varchar(10)=  DATEPART(MONTH,@calenderDate)
DECLARE @week varchar(10) =  DATEPART(WEEK,@calenderDate) 
DECLARE @hour varchar(10) =  DATEPART(HOUR,@calenderDate)

select coalesce(cast(DATEPART(YEAR,transferDateTime)as nvarchar(16)),'Year total') as year_period, 
       coalesce(cast(DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime) as nvarchar(16)),'Month total') as month_period, 
       coalesce(cast(DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime)as nvarchar(16)),'week total')  as week_period,
       coalesce(cast(DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime) as nvarchar(16)),'day total') as day_period, 
       count(t.transferAmount) as volofTxns, coalesce(sum(t.transferAmount),0) as ValueofTxns
from #transferTable t where t.transferDateTime>=@calenderDate
group by rollup (DATEPART(YEAR,transferDateTime), DATEPART(MONTH,transferDateTime), 
            DATEPART(WEEK,transferDateTime),DATEPART(DAY,transferDateTime))
order by year_period, month_period, week_period, 
               case when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '1' then 1 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '2' then 2 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '3' then 3 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '4' then 4 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '5' then 5 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '6' then 6 
                    when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '7' then 7 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '8' then 8 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '9' then 9 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '10' then 10 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '11' then 11 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '12' then 12 
                    when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '13' then 13 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '14' then 14 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '15' then 15 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '16' then 16 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '17' then 17 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '18' then 18 
                    when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '19' then 19 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '20' then 20 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '21' then 21 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '22' then 22 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '23' then 23 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '24' then 24 
                    when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '25' then 25 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '26' then 26 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '27' then 27 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '28' then 28 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '29' then 29 when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '30' then 30 
                    when datepart(day,transferdatetime) = '31' then 31 else 32 end;

drop table #transferTable;
```